# PHP: Codeigniter style-url:s?

Tags: php, url, codeigniter, frameworks, uri

I am looking for some help on how to create the sort of URL-rewriting CodeIgniter features for my own PHP pet application. 
I  know that the `.htaccess`-file does one part of the magic, but how does a PHP file looks that handles the URL splitting and calling of controllers/methods accordingly to the URI?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In [MicroMVC](http://github.com/Xeoncross/micromvc) I do this to get the URL of the page:

```
function uri()
{
//The SERVER values to look for the path info in
$server = array('PATH_INFO', 'REQUEST_URI', 'ORIG_PATH_INFO', 'REDIRECT_URL');

// Try each server var for the page URL
foreach($server as $item)
{
    if( ! empty($_SERVER[$item]) AND $uri = trim($_SERVER[$item]))
    {
        // Remove the query string (if given)
        $uri = parse_url($uri, PHP_URL_PATH);

        if($uri)
        {
            return $uri;
        }
    }
}
}
```

You can also look at the [gluephp](http://gluephp.com/) project.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a good tutorial on phpro.org:

[Model View Controller MVC](http://phpro.org/tutorials/Model-View-Controller-MVC.html)

You need to have a look at `router` class. Things will be much clear if you read entire tutorial.